# onClick - Hide/Display Div

Tags: javascript

In this i want a function that when the user click on "**Button 01**" it should make visible the DIVid "**01**". After this when click on some other button, it should it hide the previous  *DIVid* and make visible the relevant *DIVid*.

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aki_shaitan/ruDek/).

```
function Visibility() {
    var har_element = document.getElementById('C');
    var meth_element = document.getElementById('D');
    var main_element = document.getElementById('E');

    var vis = har_element.style;    

    if(vis.display == 'block') {vis.display = 'block';
        meth_element.style.display='block';
        main_element.style.display='block';
    } else {
        vis.display = 'block';
        meth_element.style.display='block';
        main_element.style.display='block';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
window.onload = function(){
hideSomeDivs();
```

}

```
function showHide(showHidebuttonId)
{
   hideAll();

if(showHidebuttonId == "1")
  document.getElementById("first").style.display = 'block';
else if(showHidebuttonId == "2")
  document.getElementById("second").style.display = 'block';
else if(showHidebuttonId == "3")
 document.getElementById("third").style.display = 'block';
else if(showHidebuttonId == "4")
  document.getElementById("fourth").style.display = 'block';
 else if(showHidebuttonId == "5")
  document.getElementById("fifth").style.display = 'block';
}

  function hideAll(){
    document.getElementById("first").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("second").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("third").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("fourth").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("fifth").style.display = 'none';
  }
  function hideSomeDivs()
  {
   document.getElementById("second").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("third").style.display = 'none';
  }
```

Comment: It would be beeter if you can create a fiddle for me.

Comment: when the page loads i can see the all all - "First - fourth" visible. How to hide this too.

Comment: call hideSomeDivs function in onload

Comment: Then it is better to apply same class then iterate all those elements.It is better to use jQuery

Comment: @jahroy jQuery is ok for u.Then it is very easy

Comment: @jahroy is it ok for u +1 please if it is helpful to you

Comment: @PSR Its working fine, but the only problem is that when the first time page loads, all 05 DivIds i.e. "First - Fifth" comes and then fade out (kind of flicker). How to remove this too.

Comment: Hey Guys, I am not able to join the chat because i don't have 20 reputation :'(

Comment: In this we are playing the function *hideSomeDivs* on window load. that is creating problem.